# Excel 2010 - Searching a range

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to search a table array for text and if that text is found, return the value in a corresponding cell for each occurrence.

Example: 
Search columns B:T for "*15-1050*"  if it is found, return the value of the  cell in column A of the row the occurrence was found.

I have a schedule of projects. I need to know which employees are working on each project.  There are several employees assigned to a project.  Column A of the sheet lists the employee name and each project that the are schedule for is listed horizontally in a cell across the row.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? You can use the `.Find` method on a range object, but you'll need to use some error-handling to account for what happens if the value is not found.

Comment: The [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) with a wildcarded [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) can return the value from column A. Are you sure that VBA is required? Hmmm... perhaps columns B:T is too wide a range to make that practical.

Answer (score 0):

The Find method searches a range for a specific keyword/value

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("B:T").Find(What:="*15-1050*")
```